# Contact form7 is not getting the right one & Hello World post is not removed

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using the most popular 'One-click-demo-import' WordPress plugin for a long time. It's a really very powerful plugin, love it. But, I face some problems after importing 'Demo data'. The 'Contact form7' is not getting the right one when there are multiple forms & the 'Hello World' post is not removed, as a result, it's ugly to show without a featured image.

Can you please help me? I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Thanks

Comment: When you run One-click-demo-import the default post will not remove 
you need to remove it manually , as well as you need to do setting to display home page below :


https://www.screencast.com/t/36NutwNn

Answer (score 0):

When you run One-click-demo-import the default post will not remove 
you need to remove it manually , as well as you need to do setting to display home page below :

Settings - Reading Settings

https://www.screencast.com/t/36NutwNn

Comment: No, the plugin can set the Menu and Homepage after importing the dummy content. Also can overwrite the post as the demo.